# Using require.js to load non-AMD files and files with other than .js extension

Tags: requirejs, js-amd

Is there any clean way to load files with other than js extension and not AMD content?

I use the *enforceDefine* config to make sure my actual AMD code works while developing.

So far I've managed to put together a plugin that sets *enforceDefine* to false, so I can load 3rd party libraries like so: `require(['noamd!handlebars'])`. That doesn't seem too much hacky to me but I'd like to know if there's a better way.

I'm currently testing the *noext* plugin and it does its job but also in a kind of a hacky way. I've noticed that it applies the noext parameter twice to the url (`test.txt?noext=1&noext=1`). I can live with that but optimally I'd like to git rid of all extra parameters. Can that be done?

Answer (score 7):

To load files that aren't JS (such as `.handlebars`, `.mustache`) then [the text plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#text) will suit your purposes.

To load normal js files you can use RequireJS as a script loader:

```
require(['full/path/to/file.js'], function(){
    // Fired when file is loaded but if non AMD
    // no value will be passed to this function
});
```

If you would like to treat the non-AMD file as a module, then [you can use the `shim` config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to implement it.

Comment: Good answer but doesn't help my situation particularly. I should've mentioned in the question that I've considered the text plugin to load non-js files too. I'm currently loading non-AMD files like you explained but I created a plugin that temporarily disables _enforceDefine_, so RequireJS won't throw an error when the file does not contain an AMD module. I also considered the shim config but quickly gave up on it. I guess it would work even in situations where you don't know beforehand if a module is going to be loaded. I just didn't have the patience with the docs :)

Answer (score 3):

you can append a ?MEH=BLAH to the end to stop the .js appending

eg

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "dynamicstripconfig": "../php/domain/config.php?dynamic=1"
    }
});
```

Additionally there a plugin for that as well, but doesn't support paths -> https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins

Added a issue with fix for path support -> https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/issues/47

If your file isn't actually a dynamic js file then use the text plugin -> https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins